# Preserve Heroku session affinity when scaling up

Tags: heroku, horizontal-scaling, sticky-session, session-affinity

According to the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity#how-it-works) when session affinity is turned on and number of Dynos (nodes) scales up the existing traffic is evenly distributed to the new Dynos.

This has affect that client of 'old' Dynos are assigned to the Dynos they have not communicated before. This is unavoidable when scaling down but is not be necessary when scaling up.

Is there a possiblity to prevent Heroku load balancer from assigning existing sessions to the new Dynos  and rather keeping them with the original ones ?

Comment: This behavior breaks my stateful service! Have you found the solution?